# Chrome-Extension : restart automatically extension through code

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using Chrome Extension to scrape web sites and once in a while the Chrome Extension crashes. To reload the crashed extension, I have created another extension that reloads the crashed extension every X minutes.

It all worked fine until recently. The extension that I was using to restart the scraper did not restart the extension anymore while I haven't changed anything to it.

Here is a sample for the alarm:

```
chrome.alarms.get(alarmName, function(Alarm) 
    {
        if (typeof Alarm === 'undefined')
            {
                console.log('is not defined');
                chrome.alarms.create(alarmName, 
                    {
                    periodInMinutes: 1
                });         
            }       
        else 
            {
                console.log('is defined');

            }       

    });
```

and then the code to restart the extension:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async function( alarm ) 
    {
        var child = null;
        chrome.management.getAll(function (info) {
            for (var i=0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].name == 'MyScraper') {
                    child = info[i];
                    console.log(child);
                    chrome.management.setEnabled(child.id, true, function () 
                    { 
                        console.log('Enabled '+Date.now());
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }); 


    });
```

The code finds the extension correctly and display the child object, the content of this object is ok but once I try to reload it with setEnabled, the console outputs "Enable + time" but the scraping extension is not restarted. I don't get any error message.

The extension is running on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Chromium, it used to run on Windows before but I don't see why the code would not work anymore.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: According [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled), `setEnabled` function must be called in the context of a user gesture (e.g. an onclick handler). So I don't think an extension can call it automatically. Otherwise it may lead to abuses.

Comment: it makes sense but they probably adapted this recently because it used to work without any user intervention. Do you see any alternative to restart my chrome extension automatically? thanks

Comment: I doubt what you described has ever been possible with an extension, at least not in regular mode. In developer mode - well, may be, though I can't imagine reason why. Your use case looks contrived to me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find a way to solve this through a Chrome Extension, I have installed xdotool and created a script that clicks on the reload button every 10 minutes. It's not super clean but at least it solves my issue.

Thanks